# setAttribute() not working?

Tags: javascript, css, shadowbox

I'm trying to add a couple of navigation "panes" to Shadowbox on [my site](http://www.element17.com/).  I found the following bit of code to do so, which is working but relies on quite a bit of inline CSS.  I'm attempting to move this out to shadowbox.css, but I can't seem to get that to work.  Here's the code:

```
var cssNavButtons = {cursor:"pointer", position:"absolute", width:200, height:"100%", top:0, "z-index":400};
var navBtnRight = $("<div/>").css(cssNavButtons).css({right: 0, background:"url('images/nav-right.png') center center no-repeat"}).click(function(){Shadowbox.next();});
var navBtnLeft = $("<div/>").css(cssNavButtons).css({left: 0, background:"url('images/nav-left.png') center center no-repeat"}).click(function(){Shadowbox.previous();});
$("#sb-body-inner").prepend(navBtnRight).prepend(navBtnLeft);
```

I have tried to set the vars navBtnRight and navBtnLeft to use the external CSS file like so, to no avail:

```
var navBtnRight = $("<div/>").setAttribute("class","sb-bignav").setAttribute("id","sb-bignav-right").click(function(){Shadowbox.next();});
```

Can anyone let me know why this wouldn't work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be using jQuery, in which case you need the [`.attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) (which works on jQuery objects), not the [`.setAttribute()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute) (which works on DOM elements).

Though to add a class I'd use [`.addClass("sb-bignav")`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) rather than `.setAttribute("class","sb-bignav")`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
element.setAttributeNS("null","attribute_name",value) .
```